# How to dump a complex template type in windbg?

Tags: debugging, windbg

How do I dump a complex template type in windbg?

I've tried

```
dt -n "mod!TypeA<TypeB,TypeC,TypeD<int,bool> >" 0x12345678
```

and several other commands but so far no luck.

Also recursive dt doesn't work here

```
dt -r <depth>
```

because I have to compute an address to get what I'm looking for.

Thx!

Comment: does `dt -n myDLL! varName` not work? you can also try `dv` if it is a variable passed to a function

Comment: Try dumping all the types in mod and see if your template type is listed: dt mod!*

Comment: @EdChum no. Also I don't have a variable name because I have to compute the address of the object.

Comment: @MarcSherman I have the full name of the type already. What I don't have is a way to dump that type at a particular address.

Comment: nope, actually, i'm an idiot. i was overthinking it. just make sure the module is specified as @EdChum indicates and do not use quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
dt -n myDLL! varName
```

or whatever the equivalent is for you, you don't need the `"` quotes.